# Error: Could not parse for environment production: Is a directory - with vagrant and puphpet

Tags: php, vagrant, puphpet

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I have this error when running `vagrant up`.

```
==> default: Error: Could not parse for environment production: Is a directory - /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-75f35e3bc7e32744860c4bb229c88812 on node local.company.com
==> default: Error: Could not parse for environment production: Is a directory - /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-75f35e3bc7e32744860c4bb229c88812 on node local.company.com
```

When I `vagrant ssh` many of the packages aren't installed (php, mysql, apache). I tried on the ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 boxes.

Here's my config.yaml

```
vagrantfile:
target: local
vm:
    box: puphpet/ubuntu1204-x64
    box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1204-x64
    hostname: local.company.com
    memory: '1024'
    cpus: '2'
    chosen_provider: virtualbox
    network:
        private_network: 192.168.56.101
        forwarded_port: {  }
    post_up_message: ''
    provider:
        virtualbox:
            modifyvm:
                natdnshostresolver1: 'on'
            showgui: '0'
        vmware:
            numvcpus: 1
        parallels:
            cpus: 1
    provision:
        puppet:
            manifests_path: puphpet/puppet/manifests
            module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
            options:
                - '--verbose'
                - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
    synced_folder:
        vflsf_wl9nzy0st9mc:
            source: ./
            target: /var/sites/devoffice
            sync_type: nfs
            smb:
                smb_host: ''
                smb_username: ''
                smb_password: ''
            rsync:
                args:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--archive'
                    - '-z'
                exclude:
                    - .vagrant/
                    - .git/
                auto: 'true'
            owner: www-data
            group: www-data
    usable_port_range:
        start: 10200
        stop: 10500
ssh:
    host: null
    port: null
    private_key_path: null
    username: vagrant
    guest_port: null
    keep_alive: true
    forward_agent: false
    forward_x11: false
    shell: 'bash -l'
    insert_key: false
vagrant:
    host: detect
server:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
locale:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_locale: ''
        locales: {  }
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
        proxy_connect_timeout: 600s
        proxy_send_timeout: 600s
        proxy_read_timeout: 600s
        names_hash_bucket_size: 128
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        nxv_1zz0kbyjvv69:
            server_name: local.company.com
            www_root: /var/www/admin-v1
            listen_port: '80'
            index_files:
                - index.php
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl: '1'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_port: '443'
            ssl_protocols: ''
            ssl_ciphers: ''
            rewrite_to_https: '1'
            spdy: '1'
            locations:
                nxvl_2665t25gmpuy:
                    location: /
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'false'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: ''
                    fastcgi_index: ''
                    fastcgi_split_path: ''
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
                nxvl_xmvfqqvh9doe:
                    location: '~ \.php$'
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'false'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: index.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename'
                        - 'APP_ENV dev'
                    set:
                        - '$path_info $fastcgi_path_info'
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
    proxies: {  }
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - proxy_fcgi
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        av_iwuq9x9j83hm:
            servername: local.company.com
            docroot: /var/sites/devoffice/admin-v1
            port: '443'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            setenvif:
                - 'Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1'
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl: '1'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '56'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
        pear: {  }
        pecl: {  }
    ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_vstyf2feqrjw:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
xdebug:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
blackfire:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        server_id: ''
        server_token: ''
        agent:
            http_proxy: ''
            https_proxy: ''
            log_file: stderr
            log_level: '1'
        php:
            agent_timeout: '0.25'
            log_file: ''
            log_level: '1'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: v0.19.0
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 6.3.0
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions: {  }
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '1'
    npm_packages: {  }
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings: {  }
    server_ini:
        hhvm.server.host: 127.0.0.1
        hhvm.server.port: '9000'
        hhvm.log.use_log_file: '1'
        hhvm.log.file: /var/log/hhvm/error.log
    php_ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        date.timezone: UTC
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '10.1'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mariadbnu_k90oiyvvczk8:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mariadbnd_65a8qo8f2pqr:
            name: dbname
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mariadbng_8r6dvf23am4e:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
mysql:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '5.5'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mysqlnu_zrpf1arlvuul:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mysqlnd_u7r68nbams0v:
            name: zaycon_db
            sql: ''
    grants: {  }
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        global:
            encoding: UTF8
            version: '9.4'
        server:
            postgres_password: '123'
    databases: {  }
    users: {  }
    grants: {  }
    adminer: 0
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        bind_ip: 127.0.0.1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mailhog:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '8025'
        path: /usr/local/bin/mailhog
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '11300'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
    users: {  }
    vhosts: {  }
    plugins: {  }
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 1.4.1
        java_install: true
solr:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 4.10.2
        port: '8984'
```

Comment: I found this post: https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/16590/error-400-on-server-could-not-parse-for-environment/ that says I need puppet 3.5. Puppet 3.4.3 is what's installed by default. This might be why but I fail to see how I could possibly be the only one experiencing this.

Comment: I ran the `vagrant box update` to update my box but it says I have the lastest version.

Comment: Having that exact same problem since some days with new boxes.

Comment: @Ethan22 `vagrant box update` will not necessarily upgrade puppet, you can do that through provisioning or directly from the box and then rerun `vagrant provision`

Comment: I tried updating puppet in the box but it kept telling me the version was 3.4.3. I don't think I was updating the right program but nothing I tried worked. do you have a page or a command I can try?

Comment: @kaiser yeah I noticed someone else posted an issue with the puphpet git with the same issue a couple hours after me. Makes me feel a little better that I'm not the only one. I wonder if this has to do with that update they posted on their main page about boxes being updated to puppet 3.4.3 on the 1st

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I spent a long time trying to update or reinstall puppet through apt-get. Turns out it was originally installed through ruby so this simple command fixes this issue.

`vagrant ssh` into server, `sudo su` then `gem install puppet`, exit server. run `vagrant provision`

UPDATE: This did turn out to be a problem of the box not being updated but the reason `vagrant box update` didn't work was because hashicorp hadn't released this box with the others when Puphpet updated their box.

Comment: Thanks! Working!
More info from @jtreminio  https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/2013#issuecomment-161830087

Comment: The "gem install puppet" can take a while so grab some coffee

Answer (score 3):

Please update your boxes. Don't install Puppet, puphpet boxes already ship with 4.3.x.

Source: am puphpet

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after upgrading Vagrant.

Execute once: `vagrant box update` before `vagrant up`.